# Generic method for Predicate Builder

Tags: c#, linq, generics, predicate

Im using LinqPad Predicatebuilder to generate a Linq-query based on dynamic input. In the code I have alot of if-cases to check if the input has a value on specific properties, like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchInput.modelname))
{
    searchPredicate = searchPredicate.And(stock => stock.ModelName.ToLower().Equals(searchInput.modelname.ToLower()));
}
```

Is there a way to create a generic method on which I could call with just the value and the name of the stock property? Like:

```
searchPredicate = AddAndPredicate(searchInput.modelName, "ModelName", searchPredicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple method which accept a set of parameter and a `delegate` to a `Func<T, TObject>` which will evaluate your condition. I will prepare a simple example for you. This is not a complete generic solution, but should be reusable very good.